# Python 3.x - Using the sum function to concatenate strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, concatenation

```
x= ['Good', 'morning'] # example list of strings
```

I have to use sum(x) to concatenate both and print (x). I'm having trouble converting the list into integers for the sum function to work.

```
>>>print (sum(x))
'Goodmorning'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work.  `sum()` is for adding up numbers, not strings.  Use `''.join()` instead.

```
>>> ''.join(['good ', 'morning'])
'good morning'
```

Answer (score 0):

From help(sum)

```
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(...)
    sum(iterable[, start]) -> value

    Return the sum of an iterable of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
    of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the iterable is
    empty, return start.
```

As @kevin suggested, use `join` function.